# Grails : Spring Security Core how to login a user two different screens and failure screens

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have an application where I would like to create two different work flows for logging a user into an application using spring-security-core. One for customer, the other for an admin. So, to sum up there would be 2 different login screens. How can I achieve this? (auth/customer_login including where to redirect on failure, auth/admin_login including where to redirect on login failure)

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are using `spring-security-core` plugin, you don't have to create different login screens for the different type of access (admin & customer). You can/should always use the role-based authority to separate the usage. For example: `ROLE_CUSTOMER` won't see or will not be able to access the pages/features designed for admins and vice-versa.

Of course, there are annotation `@Secured` and various taglibs available to achieve the same.

But even if you wanted to provide the separate login screens then you can create two different views (or two actions) and use the session to redirect them if login fails.

I'm providing you a simple outline:

```
class LoginController {

    // Action for admin login "/login/admin"
    def admin() {
        session.loginType = "ADMIN"
        // render the login view from spring-security-core
    }

    def adminFailure() {
        // do what you want after admin login failed
    }

    // Action for customer login "/login/customer"
    def customer() {
        session.loginType = "CUSTOMER"
        // render the login view from spring-security-core
    }

    def customerFailure() {
        // do what you want after customer login failed
    }

    // Acton when spring-security will redirect after any kind of failure
    def loginFailed() {
        if (session.loginType == "ADMIN") {
            redirect action: "adminFailure"
        } else if (session.loginType == "CUSTOMER") {
            redirect action: "customerFailure"
        }
    }
}
```

and set the following in your `application.groovy`:

(check the Grails & plugin version)

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl = "/login/authFailed"
```